# How to parse html using XPath and Swift 2.0?

Tags: macos, xpath, html-parsing, swift2

I am trying to parse some data form a website but I just can't get it working.

I tried NDHpple, TFHpple, Kanna all of them without success.

I want to parse:

```
<td class="date">17:08</td>
```

And the XPath I get to it, using Firebug, is:

```
/html/body/section/div/section/article/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]
```

Right now I am using Kanna and my code is this:

```
@IBAction func btnLoadData(sender: NSButton) {

    if let doc = Kanna.HTML(url: (NSURL(string: "the_site_url")!), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {


        // Search for nodes by XPath
        for link in doc.xpath("/html/body/section/div/section/article/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]") {
            print(link.text)
            print(link["href"])
        }
    }
}
```

So, anyone can help me?

Comment: what exactly you want . 17:08?

Comment: @ShubhamJain Exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed that it wasn't not working because I was trying to load from a dynamic data webpage. I tried the same code and XPath with a static data webpage that has the same data I wanted to grab and it worked like a charm.